# What “information” in document vectors makes sentiment prediction work?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, gensim, feature-selection, doc2vec

Sentiment prediction based on document vectors works pretty well, as examples show:
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb
http://linanqiu.github.io/2015/10/07/word2vec-sentiment/

I wonder what pattern is in the vectors making that possible. I thought it should be similarity of vectors making that somehow possible. Gensim similarity measures rely on cosine similarity. Therefore, I tried the following:

Randomly initialised a fix “compare” vector, get cosine similarity of the “compare” vector with all other vectors in training and test set, use the similarities and the labels of the train set to estimate a logistic regression model, evaluate the model with the test set.

Looks like this, where train/test_arrays contain document vectors and train/test_labels labels either 0 or 1. (Notice, document vectors are obtained from genism doc2vec and are well trained, predicting the test set 80% right if directly used as input for the logistic regression):

```
fix_vec = numpy.random.rand(100,1)
def cos_distance_to_fix(x):
    return scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(fix_vec, x)

train_arrays_cos =  numpy.reshape(numpy.apply_along_axis(cos_distance_to_fix, axis=1, arr=train_arrays), newshape=(-1,1))
test_arrays_cos = numpy.reshape(numpy.apply_along_axis(cos_distance_to_fix, axis=1, arr=test_arrays), newshape=(-1,1))

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(train_arrays_cos, train_labels)
classifier.score(test_arrays_cos, test_labels)
```

It turns out, that this approach does not work, predicting the test set only to 50%....
So, my question is, what “information” is in the vectors, making the prediction based on vectors work, if it is not the similarity of vectors? Or is my approach simply not possible to capture similarity of vectors correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less a question about Doc2Vec than about machine-learning principles with high-dimensional data.

Your approach is collapsing 100-dimensions to a single dimension – the distance to your *random* point. Then, you're hoping that single dimension can still be predictive.

And roughly all LogisticRegression can do with that single-valued input is try to pick a threshold-number that, when your distance is on one side of that threshold, predicts a class – and on the other side, predicts not-that-class.

Recasting that single-threshold-distance back to the original 100-dimensional space, it's essentially trying to find a hypersphere, around your random point, that does a good job collecting all of a single class either inside or outside its volume.

What are the odds your randomly-placed center-point, plus one adjustable radius, can do that well, in a complex high-dimensional space? My hunch is: not a lot. And your results, no better than random guessing, seems to suggest the same.

The LogisticRegression with access to the full 100-dimensions finds a discriminating-frontier for assigning the class that's described by 100 coefficients and one intercept-value – and all of those 101 values (free parameters) can be adjusted to improve its classification performance.

In comparison, your alternative LogisticRegression with access to only the one 'distance-from-a-random-point' dimension can pick just one coefficient (for the distance) and an intercept/bias. It's got 1/100th as much information to work with, and only 2 free parameters to adjust.

As an analogy, consider a much simpler space: the surface of the Earth. Pick a 'random' point, like say the South Pole. If I then tell you that you are in an unknown place 8900 miles from the South Pole, can you answer whether you are more likely in the USA or China? Hardly – both of those 'classes' of location have lots of instances 8900 miles from the South Pole.

Only in the extremes will the distance tell you for sure which class (country) you're in – because there are parts of the USA's Alaska and Hawaii further north and south than parts of China. But even there, you can't manage well with just a single threshold: you'd need a rule which says, "less than X *or* greater than Y, in USA; otherwise unknown".

The 100-dimensional space of Doc2Vec vectors (or other rich data sources) will often only be sensibly divided by far more complicated rules. And, our intuitions about distances and volumes based on 2- or 3-dimensional spaces will often lead us astray, in high dimensions.

Still, the Earth analogy does suggest a way forward: there are *some reference points* on the globe that will work way better, when you know the distance to them, at deciding if you're in the USA or China. In particular, a point at the center of the US, or at the center of China, would work really well.

Similarly, you may get somewhat better classification accuracy if rather than a random `fix_vec`, you pick either (a) any point for which a class is already known; or (b) some average of all known points of one class. In either case, your `fix_vec` is then likely to be "in a neighborhood" of similar examples, rather than some random spot (that has no more essential relationship to your classes than the South Pole has to northern-Hemisphere temperate-zone countries).

(Also: alternatively picking N multiple random points, and then feeding the N distances to your regression, will preserve more of the information/shape of the original Doc2Vec data, and thus give the classifier a better chance of finding a useful separating-threshold. Two would likely do better than your one distance, and 100 might approach or surpass the 100 original dimensions.)

Finally, some comment about the Doc2Vec aspect:

Doc2Vec optimizes vectors that are somewhat-good, within their constrained model, at predicting the words of a text. Positive-sentiment words tend to occur together, as do negative-sentiment words, and so the trained doc-vectors tend to arrange themselves in similar positions when they need to predict similar-meaning-words. So there are likely to be 'neighborhoods' of the doc-vector space that correlate well with predominantly positive-sentiment or negative-sentiment words, and thus positive or negative sentiments.

These won't necessarily be two giant neighborhoods, 'positive' and 'negative', separated by a simple boundary –or even a small number of neighborhoods matching our ideas of 3-D solid volumes. And many subtleties of communication – such as sarcasm, referencing a not-held opinion to critique it, spending more time on negative aspects but ultimately concluding positive, etc – mean incursions of alternate-sentiment words into texts. A fully-language-comprehending human agent could understand these to conclude the 'true' sentiment, while these word-occurrence based methods will still be confused.

But with an adequate model, and the right number of free parameters, a classifier might capture some generalizable insight about the high-dimensional space. In that case, you can achieve reasonably-good predictions, using the Doc2Vec dimensions – as you've seen with the ~80%+ results on the full 100-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Thank you for that long answer! I see what you say about the dimension reduction. Makes sense for me. But this also turns the question in opposite direction for me: If a vector has 100 dimensions, each dimension bearing useful information for sentiment prediction, why is cosine distance then a good measure for semantically related sentences? Hence, is it possible to train a classifier to find semantically related sentences and get “better” results then by using cosine distance measure?

Comment: Cosine distance is a common & easy measure of vector-similarity – considering vectors normed-directions, without regard to magnitude. It so happens that in the underlying NN, input vectors of identical directions (0.0 cosine-distance) will make the same ranked output predictions (just scaled by magnitude), & those with small cosine-distances give similar predictions. So this kind of distance fits the model, and turns out to often work well. (Still: if all vectors are unit-normed, euclidean distance will yield the same rankings of nearest-neighbors.)

Comment: It's *possible* some other feature-transform on the raw doc-vecs could, coupled with the right classifier, yield a better final result – more generalizable, better-scoring by some evaluation. Maybe the 'neighborhoods' of sentiment, in the original space, aren't cleanly separable by a LogisticRegression – but would be, with other synthesized dimensions or another classification model. (Your transformation of the 100d to a single radius value was essentially applying a `radial basis` kernel - *if* the classes were separable by a sphere, & the right center was chosen, that'd be a great approach.)